# bootstrap 4 vertical alignment

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-4

What I am trying to achieve is this:
1 long left column- and next to it, 2 rows on the right, that together - align up to the left column.
In a table it would super easy to do:

```
----------------------------
|         |                |
|   col-4 |     col-8      |
|         |                |
|         |________________|
|         |                |
|         |                |
|         |      col-8     |
|         |                |
----------------------------
```

My code looks like this, but its only half way there: I cant get the second row `col-8` to move up to its twin (other than some kind of custom made double `row` with a negative `margin-top`).

```
<div class="row d-flex flex-row-reverse">
  <div class="col-sm-8 align-self-start">888</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4" style="height: 400px;">444</div>
  <div class="col-sm-8 ">888</div>
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kneidels/4yh0vqv0/2/)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the normal markup tree of container, row, col you can just put your tall `col-sm-4` first followed by a `col-sm-8` and add the class of `d-flex flex-column` to the `col-sm-8` and then inside of the `col-sm-8` you can have 2 divs with the class of `col` and they will fill the area of their parent so your markup would look like the following:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="height:400px;">Regular col-sm-4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 d-flex flex-column p-0">
      <div class="col">Flex item inside col-sm-8</div>
      <div class="col">Flex item inside col-sm-8</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If your not using bootstraps markup tree then you will have to initiate the flex behavior on the outside div like so:

```
<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="col-sm-4" style="height:400px;">Regular col-sm-4</div>
  <div class="col-sm-8 d-flex flex-column p-0">
    <div class="col">Flex item inside col-sm-8</div>
    <div class="col">Flex item inside col-sm-8</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So how this works is bootstrap's rows use the flex behavior already to create their grid so they already have the `display:flex` in the row's css and by adding the `.col` class inside of your `d-flex flex-column` you are initiating the flex behavior on your `.col-sm-8` and the `.col` class has flex-grow: 1;` in the css already so your child containers of your flex column will fill the height.

Hope that makes sense here is an updated fiddle [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/w4vf9f4c/)

Note: You will probably want to add the class of `p-0` to the flex-column to eliminate the columns padding like I have done in the above examples

Comment: Thank you @steve-k! Question: this does not seem to work when the 2 rows on the right need to be different heights, right?

Comment: You can just remove the .col class from one of the right columns don't think it matters which one and maybe give it the class of px-3 so it has the same padding as the .col then the remaining .col will just fill the extra room in the flex column.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of browser support do you need for this? One possible attack would be using [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/). Grid is [relatively well supported](https://caniuse.com/#search=css%20grid), and getting better all the time.

Comment: All modern browsers + mobile. I am pretty much stuck on using bootstrap